# Test if a job id exists APScheduler

Tags: apscheduler

Is there a simpler way of testing whether or not a job id exists other than using .get_jobs() and iterating through the list?

For instance something like:

```
if schedule.get_job(id='start1'):
    do this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you've checked the [API documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.get_job)?

So:

```
if scheduler.get_job('start1'):
   ...
```